# mongodb schema design to store cart rule

Tags: mongodb, schema, nosql

I am working on a e-commerce site that uses mongodb to store the data. One of the modules will be a price/cart rule where a user will be given a coupon which they can place at checkout to get a discount.

That is working fine and is standard, what I am unsure is how best to keep track of the number of times the user has used that coupon and in which collection to store this?

This is the model I have thus far:

```
schema = new mongoose.Schema
  name: 
    type: String
    required: true
  description: i18nString.schema
  coupon:
    type: String
    index: true
  type:
    type: String
    enum: ["cart", "price"]
    required: true
  quantity:
    type: Number
    default: 1
  user_qty:
    type: Number
    default: 1
  from: 
    type: Date
    required: true
  to: 
    type: Date
    required: true
  discount: 
    type: Number
    default: 0
    required: true
  log: [
    user:
      type: ObjectId
      ref: "User"
    updatedAt: Date
    status: String
  ]
  status:
    type: String
    enum: ["draft", "active", "archived"]
    default: "draft"
    required: true
```

this gives me a document like:

```
> db.rules.find({}).pretty();
{
    "__v" : 3,
    "_id" : ObjectId("561e53dfa7e6f5f91c63e32d"),
    "coupon" : "Y3E3TL-3FE00W-DDR7PP-RR27Y8",
    "description" : {
        "en-UK" : "English description"
    },
    "discount" : 10,
    "quantity": 500,
    "user_qty": 5,
    "from" : ISODate("2015-10-13T23:00:00Z"),
    "log" : [
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("55848edda14c975ac907ad6d"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-14T13:08:47.956Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("561e53dfa7e6f5f91c63e32e")
        },
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("55848edda14c975ac907ad6d"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-14T13:09:11.592Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("561e53f7a7e6f5f91c63e32f")
        },
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("55848edda14c975ac907ad6d"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-14T14:46:03.289Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("561e6aab4adfac513594bbe6")
        },
        {
            "user" : ObjectId("55848edda14c975ac907ad6d"),
            "updatedAt" : ISODate("2015-10-15T09:44:55.827Z"),
            "_id" : ObjectId("561f7597efe4eb424baac50f")
        }
    ],
    "name" : "Coupon name",
    "status" : "draft",
    "to" : ISODate("2015-10-23T23:00:00Z"),
    "type" : "cart"
}
```

I have a user collection, so should i store it inside the user document or is it better to have a coupon-log collection and count how many times the user has used a specific coupon and compare this with the user_qty from the rule collection?

Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to go about this is to embed an array on each user record and store all coupons with their unique properties in there. This is because even if you would create a different collection to store coupons, you would still have to store a reference to those coupons' in your user records, thus still creating an additional field.

Still, if coupons are shared and can be used by multiple users at the same time, you might want to create a different collection in order to avoid the duplication of data.

It all starts with the user interaction patterns - taking into account your structure, I think coupon actions might fall in one of the following scenarios:

- Coupons can be used multiple times, by multiple users
- Coupons can be used multiple times, but only by one user
- Coupons are unique and can only be used once by multiple users
- Coupons are unique and can only be used once by one single user

Thus, if coupons are bound to users, I recommend you embed an array with a schema similar to the one below:

```
coupons: [
    {
        coupon: "Y3E3TL-3FE00W-DDR7PP-RR27Y8",
        hits: 10,
        ...
        //additional fields
    },

    {
        coupon: "G547XW-F9JW04-RXFP77-7JJ0CE",
        hits: 9,
        ...
        //additional fields 
    }
]
```

Otherwise, if coupons are shared, I think you might be better off by storing all coupons in their own collection and reference them in your user records. Thus, you might only have the coupon and hits fields in your user records, while all the other data is stored in the coupons collection:

```
coupons: [
    {
        couponRef: ObjectId("561e53dfa7e6f5f91c63e32d"),
        hits: 10
    },

    {
        couponRef: ObjectId("427e53dfa7e6f5f91c63e32d"),
        hits: 9
    }
]
```

Comment: *"Usually, in MongoDB, it is recommended to try and embed documents as much as possible."*  This assertion is false, especially with unbounded arrays.

Comment: I removed that assertion in order to not confuse people. Thank you for the comment.

Comment: @VladZ. thanks for this, in some cases coupons will be shared across users, so i will reference the coupon inside the user.